# Monitor offline adwords conversions

Tags: google-ads, conversions

I'm trying to evaluate the usefulness of Google Adwords for a friend's site. I'm trying to count the number of sales per month, and see how many have found her page because of the Adwords campaign. Her site has an online order system, but she also gets customers that buy just via the email contact and never use the online order system.

There aren't many conversions per month (usually only one to three), so I don't want to miss any conversions when I want to gauge the effectiveness of a campaign. Is there a good way to also include those conversions?

Comment: Does the landing page when they click through the add include the email ordering option, or do they click to other parts of the site to find it?

Comment: They land on a general page with the products, and probably find the email address on the 'contact' page.

Comment: Create a landing page and put a coupon code on it - the cost of offering the coupon will probably be less than maintaining an unnecessary AdWords campaign.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing an email address, maybe provide a page with an HTML contact form which can generate the email. Then customer contact in this manner would be logged in Google Analytics and could be tied back to your AdWords campaign.  This still wouldn't log sales transactions in Analytics, but presumably you can keep track of sales that come from the contact form in the back end.

I'm not sure if this helps, but sometimes one idea might spark another :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would be asking yourself why the customers are splitting between website and email orders.

I would be tempted to remove the ability to email orders from the site and force them to use the one sales channel.  Then if any email orders come through you know they aren't coming via the site and therefore not coming from Adwords directly (I say directly because they might have visited via Adwords and bought later)

This will initially feel like removing functionality, but it will also add a layer of professionalism, I can't think of any large e-commerce site that allows people to email in orders, it is too wishy washy.